# Pass javascript variable to ruby locals

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to pass `javascript` variable to `rails` `locals`.

I have `.js.erb` file where I am fetching the `post` and `comment` number from the `DOM` through `jquery`. But I need to send this variable in `rails` `locals`.

Here is my `.js.erb` file code.

```
var label = $("#post_4375").find('label').text().split(")")[0].split(".");
var post_num = label[0];
var comment_num = label[1];

$("#post_"<%= @post.id %>).html('<%=j render partial: "comments/comment",  locals: { post: @post, comment: @comment, post_num: post_num, comment_num: comment_num } %>');
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

There is another way that I will send this through `params`. But I not really want that way as this stuff is running conditionally.

Comment: This `"#post_"+<%= @post.id %>` should be `"#post_<%= @post.id %>"`

Comment: The JS code executes on the client, *long* after the Ruby code has been executed on the server. Because of this the two languages cannot interact directly like you're attempting. To do what you require you would need to use AJAX.